# add buttons(from code) on the Navigation Controller and make them disappear

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have added a button from the code above "view controller":

```
@implementation HBViewController
.....
.....
.....

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    okButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(okayButtonPressed)];

    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:okButton animated:NO];

}

- (void) okayButtonPressed{
NSLog(@"you pressed ok");
}
```

...But how can I hide the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
            //to disable

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;

            //to hide - hide means setting nil will remove that button

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;


            //if u want to show again then create and assign new button again

        okButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ok" 

                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered

                  target:self action:@selector(okayButtonPressed)];

        [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:okButton animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set it nil

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
```