# how to disable click on back button, iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having back button and edit button on my navigation bar like below
[image]

After clicking on the Edit button, I have

[image]

**My question** : how can I disable click on back button when I am in edit mode so that user can not go back previous screen until he  or she is done.....

What I am trying is

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled   =   NO;
```

but the back button is still clickable

PS : The way I add back button to navigation bar is

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton             =   NO;
```

I can hide back button but I dont want that option...

Please advice me on this issue. Any comments are welcomed here.

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718686/add-buttonsfrom-code-on-the-navigation-controller-and-make-them-disappear/10718900#10718900>

Comment: I think this would be a bad idea--and probably violate how people expect apps to work. I recommend @Sulthan's first suggestion: let people click "Back" but just end edit mode when they do. You might want to look into how other apps handle a similar situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to end edit mode when you are leaving the screen, maybe displaying a confirmation alert first (`UIAlertView` with two buttons "Ok" and "Cancel").

However, to answer the question - you would have to create a `UIButton` with the same appearance as a back button (using images). Create a `UIBarButtonItem` with this button as its custom view and use it in `leftBarButtonItem` (note that `backBarButtonItem` cannot have custom views).

Then you would be able to set `enabled` to `NO` on that custom view.

EDIT: I was wrong. `UIBarButtonItem` has `enabled` property. The problem with disabling the back button was there probably because you were disabling `backBarButtonItem` on the wrong `navigationItem`. The back button is always defined by the previous controller in the stack.

Comment: you could just put a transparent button over the real back button too--I think that's easier.. however this sounds like terrible UI

Comment: even though it does not have custom views but bacBarButtonItem is UIBarButtonItem and UIBarButtonItem is a subclass of UIBarItem and UIBarItem does have `enalble' property. So why cant we use it.

Answer (score 1):

If the button is blocked maybe you should hide it. Because in my point of view having a unresponsive button is not good for the user.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35f animations:^{
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = editing;       
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled   =   NO;

Where you put the above code. place the above code in edit button's IBAction method.

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem` is not subclass of `UIView` and does not have `enabled` property. What you have answered is not correct.

Comment: UIBarButtonItem is a subclass of UIBarItem and UIBarItem does have `enabled` property. so his solution is correct but i dont know why it does not work

Comment: @ttran You are right I have never noticed that `UIBarButtonItem` has another superclass.