# make invisible a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I can make an invisible UIBarButtonItem on UIToolbar, inserted with XCode / Storyboard?
I have found a property to disable it: enabled = NO, but is not made it invisible

Comment: pls see my answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718686/add-buttonsfrom-code-on-the-navigation-controller-and-make-them-disappear/10718752#10718752

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSMutableArray *items = [YourToolBar.items mutableCopy];
    [items removeObject:BarButton];
    YourToolBar.items = items;
    [items release];
```