# add/hide UITabBarItem

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have a UITabBarController and would like to add a tab, with the ability to make it disappear. I added 2 tabs with XCode. You can add a third tab by program?
I know a command like:

```
  [self setViewControllers: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: x1, nil] animated: NO];
```

You can retrieve the array that uses XCode to add a third view?
thanks

---

I can not load the view with the code. I created a view controller from the storyboard, when I try to load it from code I get a black screen, use this code:

```
ViewControllerA *x1 = [[ViewControllerA alloc] init];
[self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: x1, nil] animated:NO];
```

Comment: [Please Check How to Hide Bar Button][1] 
 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753233/make-invisible-a-uibarbuttonitem/10753376#10753376

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you use [`[UITabViewController setViewControllers: animated:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarController/setViewControllers%3aanimated%3a) you can add in an array containing the two previous view controllers plus the new third one.

For example, you'd probably want to do it something like this:

```
// assuming you've set an IBOutlet to your tab bar controller
NSArray * currentSetOfViewControllers = [appTabBarController viewControllers];
if((currentSetOfViewControllers == NULL) || [currentSetOfViewControllers count] == 0))
{
    NSLog( @"I don't see any view controllers; is my tab bar controller outlet set properly?")
} else {
    NSMutableArray newSetOfViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: currentSetOfViewControllers];
    if(newSetOfViewControllers)
    {
        ViewControllerA *x1 = [[ViewControllerA alloc] init];
        if(x1)
        {
            [newSetOfViewControllers addObject: x1];

            [appTabBarController setViewControllers: newSetOfViewControllers];

            // release our alloc'd mutable array only if you do not have ARC turned on
            [newSetOfViewControllers release];
        }
    }
}
```

You'd probably also want to give your new view controller an associated tab bar item with a title and an image.  Check out [`[UITabBarItem initWithTitle: image: tag:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarItem/initWithTitle%3aimage%3atag%3a).

I've linked the Apple documentation for you which I hope would help!

Answer (score 0):

create a custom tab bar in delegate so create a view just like a tab bar and set 1 image view on view and 3 button (1 button set hidden) add this view in tab bar controller after that when u require 3rd button enable third  button